# How to keep elements visible, after they leave the viewport, after their 1st render, using "content-visibility: auto"?

Tags: css, performance

I target a css class with content-visibility: auto. I have multiple elements with that css class on the page. I would like to keep these elements visible once they render. How can I achieve that?

```
.lazyelement {
    content-visibility: auto;
}
```

I tried this script but didn't work.

```
<script type="module">
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries, o) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        let el = entry.target;
        // Not currently in intersection area.
        if (entry.intersectionRatio == 0) {
          return;
        }
        // Trigger rendering for elements within
        // scroll area that haven't already been
        // marked.
        if (!el.markedVisible) {
          el.attributeStyleMap.set(
            "content-visibility",
            "visible"
          );
          el.markedVisible = true;
        }
      });
    },
    // Set a rendering "skirt" 50px above
    // and 100px below the main scroll area.
    { rootMargin: "50px 0px 100px 0px" }
  );

  let els =
    document.querySelectorAll(".lazyelement");
  els.forEach((el) => { observer.observe(el); });
</script>
```